# SignalR in Swift using SwiftR - Error During Negotiation Request

Tags: swift, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, swiftr

I'm using .netcore with VS community edition on my Mac and would like to use SignalR for an iOS app using SwiftR

I got a working project directly from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac

and ran it locally and it worked inside of visual studio - it spun up at localhost:5000, and I even used the sample view they had to perform some SignalR commands. Everything looked great! **It works!**

Now I'm trying to utilize [SwiftR](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) and basically just do a simple call out to  SignalR running locally to prove it works in Swift. (http://localhost:5000/chatHub)

I'm getting the error: Error during negotiation request

The output is this:

```
started
Error: Optional(["message": Error during negotiation request.])
disconnected
```

Here is my code - any ideas what's going on? I'm using the exact code Microsoft provided (which seems to run fine) but Swift isn't liking it.

In my podfile, i'm just using

```
pod 'SwiftR'
```

and in a misc viewController to test it out, I'm doing this:

```
func testThis()
    {
        // Client
        let connection = SignalR("http://localhost:5000/chatHub")

        let simpleHub = Hub("ChatHub")
        simpleHub.on("SendMessage") { args in
            let message = args![0] as! String
            let detail = args![1] as! String
            print("Message: \(message)\nDetail: \(detail)")
        }

        connection.addHub(simpleHub)
        connection.starting = { print("started") }
        connection.connected = { print("connected: \(connection.connectionID)") }
        connection.connectionSlow = { print("connectionSlow") }
        connection.reconnecting = { print("reconnecting") }
        connection.reconnected = { print("reconnected") }
        connection.disconnected = { print("disconnected") }
        connection.error = { error in
            print("Error: \(error)")

            if let source = error?["source"] as? String, source == "TimeoutException" {
                print("Connection timed out. Restarting...")
                connection.start()
            }
        }
        connection.start()

        do {
            try
            // Invoke server method
            simpleHub.invoke("SendMessage", arguments: ["Simple Test", "This is a simple message"])
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        // Invoke server method and handle response
          do {
            try simpleHub.invoke("SendMessage", arguments: ["Simple Test", "This is a simple message"]) { (result, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("Error: \(e)")
            } else {
                print("Success!")
                if let r = result {
                    print("Result: \(r)")
                }
            }
        }
        }
          catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

in viewDidLoad() i'm just calling testThis()

I even modified the .net code to allow cors like this:

```
services.AddCors();
```

and then further down

```
 app.UseCors(cors =>
            {
                cors.AllowAnyHeader();
                cors.AllowAnyOrigin();
                cors.AllowAnyMethod();
            });
```

but it still continues to say

```
Error: Optional(["message": Error during negotiation request.])
```

Really appreciate any insight anyone can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftR doesn't support ASP.NET Core SignalR, you can try https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift instead. Though this doesn't talk specifically about the iOS client ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR are different products https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply - do you think I can just use the old aspnet signal r instead? I assumed not because I’m using visual studio community / .netcore on my Mac (although I do push my code to a windows server box with iis for non-local environments) THANKS

Comment: Old SignalR isn't supported on non-windows machines. Mono might work but its not something we test.

Comment: You can also consider using the Azure SignalR Service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me. In my case I was hosting a **SignalR Core application on IIS**, trying to access it through SwiftR and Moozzyk's client. Turns out WebSockets was not enabled on my host machine, which was a deal breaker since the referred clients only use WebSockets (no fallback to other transport methods like Server-Sent Events, Long Polling, etc).

Enabling WebSockets on IIS solved the issue for me. Here is a link on how to do it: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket